# crm2011 paging with silverlight and Odata

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to silverlight and odata.Currently i am working in crm 2011 where i need to pull out data from crm 2011 using server side paging just like look up in crm 2011 with silverlight and odata.Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look at an msdn Example like this [article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985388.aspx)

It's worth noting that using the rest endpoing the maximum number of records you can return at one time is 50. And that you have to look at what the result you get to determine if there are more records. The article details this as well...

```
The ProcessPages callback method determines if any more records exist and 
if they do, it uses the DataServiceQueryContinuation(T) Class. The 
DataServiceQueryContinuation  class contains a single property, NextLinkUri 
which provides URL that contains the $skiptoken parameters that describes the 
paging boundary.
```